# Create image buttons in jquery mobile

Tags: mobile

Im trying to create a button in jquery mobile only with a image and no text, as far as able to do is to add a data-icon, But  i have i feeling it could be done better.

```
<a onclick="newfunction();" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create button with only images :

```
<img style="height: 40px; width: 40px;" id="newid" data-role="button" src="source\images\greenplus.png" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data-iconpos="notext"
```

is indeed the right-way ahead for you to create a button with no text, but image only.

But i would change the onclick function that you have written. Instead of  :

```
<a onclick="newfunction();" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" ></a>
```

Try out :

```
<a class="plus_button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" ></a>
```

Since you are using jquery, use maximum jquery and your function would be :

```
$(".plus_button").click(function(){
   //something here
});
```

Cheers.